# Dynamic Key in json2json-transform - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, transform

```
I need to put dynamic Key Using Mapper
I am using json2json-transform module
Mapper Looks Like This
```

{
"THIS_VALUE_TO_BE_DYNAMIC" ":"anyValue"
}

```
Here THIS_VALUE_TO_BE_DYNAMIC value to be dynamic from JSON Object
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have written.

Comment: This is the mapper. and transform code is simple
jsonTojson.transform(JSON.parse(apiResponse), jsonDataFromResponseMapper);

I want to know if its possible to have dyanmic key here,